# How to install Ubuntu from a USB key using syslinux?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, syslinux

I'm making a bootable USB key for myself, and one function of it is to install Ubuntu.

I have downloaded the ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso file.

There is a pretty good method for [installation of Red Hat from a USB drive](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/RHEL/Installation/installation_from_usb_drive.shtml), but the problem is, when it comes to Ubuntu, what should the syslinux.cfg file be?

I used `syslinux -d /boot/syslinux /dev/sdb1` and put vmlinuz and initrd.img inside it.

Is the following item of syslinux.cfg correct?

```
LABEL InstallUbuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu 11.10 Install
KERNEL /boot/syslinux/vmlinuz
APPEND linux load_ramdisk=1 initrd=/boot/syslinux/initrd.img method=hd:sdb1:/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LABEL InstallUbuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu 11.10 Install
LINUX /vmlinuz
INITRD /initrd.lz
APPEND boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

solved the problem.

See also [there](http://www.syslinux.org/archives/2011-January/015991.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you boot Ubuntu select "Try Ubuntu"

Open a terminal and run `usb-creator-gtk`, Ubuntu will copy itself to your USB with a complete syslinux install.

Ubuntu boots from the /casper/vmlinux

If you just wanted to edit an existing syslinux.cfg
These are the relevant lines Ubuntu uses after following the above procedure

```
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append noprompt boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I what I mean is that the bootable usb key is also a installer for ubuntu. I have found the solution, see http://www.syslinux.org/archives/2011-January/015991.html

Comment: This is the installer. If you follow the usb-creator the menu has all options but an "Install Ubuntu" icon is always on the desktop regardless. There are many ways to slice and dice this one.